@iFrame-resizer/react implementation error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 's', "scroll-to-top" is not valid JSON
I am using the latest version of iframe-resizer/react for automatically adjusting the height and width of the iframe.
Whenever I'm reacting the content, I'm getting a runtime error stating -
VM2860:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 's', "scroll-to-top" is not valid JSON
I don't know from where this is coming.
I have checked the events that are coming iframe. There also, nothing called scroll-to-top is mentioned.
Below is the code snippet I have written.
Please help me to solve this issue.
import IFrameResizer from "@iframe-resizer/react";

<IFrameResizer
          src={iframeSrc}
          license="GPLv3"
          className="iframe-dialog"
          title="Iframe Dialog"
          onLoad={onLoad}
          scrolling={false}
          forwardRef={iframeRef}
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            border: "none",
            opacity: "100",
            height: "100vh",
          }}
 />

I have tried onResized, onMessage handlers given in iframe-resizer/react to get the message, but still nothing happened.

Can you add an example of the problem online somewhere please.

Sorry, what example? the error's one?

Yes please, I can’t say what the issue is without seeing it running.
